# Unable to debug azure function locally

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I wrote a simple azure function on the Azure portal and now since I've to add some more trivial code I decided to write it with vs2017 enterprise then package the dll and deploy it.
My azure function is a timer function and when I try to run it locally I got this

[image: Log]

where should I set this config.UserTimers()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to see if you are debuging in "Release" or "Debug" mode on the tool bar

The correct mode should be "Debug"
[image]

When running in release mode .pdb files are not get created and then you can't debug

Answer (score 0):

This is done by the underlying WebJobs SDK.
Scheduling for Azure Functions is explained hereafter : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer